# Type safe extension of mapped object type

Tags: typescript

Imagine you have a type like this:

```
type Person = {
  email: string
  name: string
  passport: { series: string, number: string } // or just Passport type
}
```

And now somewhere you want to have a collection of disabled keys, something like this:

```
const disabledKeys = {
  email: true,
  passport: {
    series: true
  }
}
```

So I started from that type for disabledKeys:

```
type DisabledKeys = {
  [key in keyof Person]?: boolean
}
```

but I want to describe proper shape of `passport`, so I did the following:

```
type DisabledKeys = { [key in keyof Person]?: boolean } & {
  passport: Record<keyof Passport, boolean>
  foo: number // <---- `foo` isn't a part of Person type
}
```

How can I better implement this extension part? I want it to be type-safe and include only keys from `Person` type. But currently it may contain any keys. And if I, for example, rename `passport` in person to something else, I won't receive compile time error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're probably looking for here is a [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) type of [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) property types:

```
type NestedDisabledKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]?:
  T[K] extends object ? NestedDisabledKeys<T[K]> : true;
}

type DisabledKeys = NestedDisabledKeys<Person>
```

The type `NestedDisabledKeys` walks down recursively through all object-typed properties.  For non-object properties, it allows the property to be missing (so all props are optional) or the value `true` (I assume you don't ever intend to put `false` in there, but if you do, you can change `true` to `boolean` like in your code).  This automatically builds the structure you're looking for without your having to worry about doing it correctly or incorrectly by hand.

Let's see it in action:

```
const disabledKeys: DisabledKeys = {
  email: true,
  passport: {
    series: true
  }
}

const badDisabledKeys: DisabledKeys = {
  email: true,
  passpork: {  // error! did you mean "passport"?
    series: true
  } 
}

const badDisabledKeys2: DisabledKeys = {
  email: true,
  passport: { 
    series: true
  },
  foo: true; // error! "foo" is not expected in obj literal
}


const badDisabledKeys3: DisabledKeys = {
  email: true,
  passport: {  
    series: true,
    nomber: true, // error! did you mean "number"?    
  } 
}
```

Does that work for you?  There's a wrinkle here in that even object-property keys can be missing, such as:

```
const okayDisabledKeys: DisabledKeys = {
  email: true
}
```

I assume that's acceptable and means that none of `passport` *including all subproperties* is disabled, right?  If you want to require that every object-type key be specified then the answer will be more complicated.

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!